# Does my odd proof for the Abel sum for $\eta(-2)$ work?

Tags: solution-verification, divergent-series, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation, summation-method

EDIT: The correct answer to the Abel sum of $\eta(-2)$ has been given by the comments under this post. The focus of the question is now whether there is any sense to my method and my "proof" of $\eta(-2)=0$.

OP:

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839930/how-to-apply-the-abel-summation-on-this-series) stack exchange post, I attempted to perform an Abel sum for $\eta(-2)$, since I read from Wikipedia that $\eta$ is Abel summable, which I assume implies Abel summable *everywhere*. By $\eta$ I mean Dirichlet's eta function $$\eta(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^{-z}$$

I only read about Abel sums last night, and am very much uneducated on the subject of analytic continuation, so I tried to show that $\eta(-2)=0$ without any help by way of practice - I might have succeeded, but my methods are strange and I am myself unsure whether I can do the kind of things I'm doing! My approach was as follows:

$$A\text{-}\eta(-2)=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\eta_n\cdot x^n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^2\cdot x^n$$
$$A\text{-}\eta(-2)=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left[0+x-4x^2+9x^3\dots\right]=\text{?}$$

I did not know where to go from here, but I looked for a simple derivative or integral trick, as the post I referenced had made.

*EDIT: This is the strange part that I would like a formal proof verification of*:

$$\int(-1)^{n-1}n^2\cdot x^n\space dn=\frac{(-1)}{n}^n\cdot n^2\cdot x^n-\int\frac{(-1)}{n}^n\cdot 2n\cdot x^n\cdot\ln|x|\space dn=n(-x)^n-2\ln|x|\int(-x)^n\space dn=$$

$$n(-x)^n-2\ln|x|\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^2\cdot x^n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{d}{dn}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-x)^n-2\ln|x|\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]=\frac{d}{dn}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-1)^n\right]=\frac{d}{dn}\left[1-1+2-3+4\dots\right]=0\text{?!}$$

which is seemingly correct, although it seems far too strange and I'm sure this is a mistaken pseudo-proof.

Perhaps

$$\frac{d}{dn}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-1)^n\right]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n+n^2(-1)^{n-1}=\eta(-2)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n$$
although this is a contradictory nightmare suggesting that $\eta(-2)=\eta(-2)+L$ where $L$ is the rightmost sum, either taken to be divergent or $\frac{1}{2}$, depending on the context! And so  I have shown my utter ignorance, since to me this all seems like conjectured nonsense, even though I appreciate the principle and I fail to see an error in my calculations...

Please help! I'm looking for intuition/direct proof for the Abel sum of $\eta(-2)$ and for the errors in my insane and uneducated attempt to tackle this. I'm especially curious as to whether an expression like $\frac{d}{dn}\sum_na_n$ even works, and as to whether my "answer" $\frac{d}{dn}\left[1-1+2-3\dots\right]=0$ is accidentally correct, or pure nonsense.

And please bear in mind when you answer/comment that my "knowledge" of analytic continuation and "super-summing" comes only from two Mathologer YouTube videos :) so my language and statements are probably going to seem very off.

Comment: Show that the series is the derivative of $z/(1+z)^2$ by the method of the linked post; the result follows

Comment: Yes.  The eta function will have zero value at all negative even integers.  It looks strange, but it's true.

Comment: @OscarLanzi does the "it looks strange but it's true" idea hold for my weird d/dn[...] = 0 at the end?

Comment: @Conrad I'll try that, thank you

Comment: @Conrad I have managed to write $\sum (-1)^{n-1}n^2x^{n-1}=\sum n\left[(-1)^{n-1}nx^{n-1}\right]=\sum \frac{d}{dx}-n(-x)^n$ which looks very close to the geometric series sum you suggested but I can’t quite finish it off... I’m not sure how to create the form $\frac{a}{1-r}$ with $a=x$

Comment: the post linked at the top gives $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)z^n =\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$; note that your sum (index shifted so it is $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)^2z^n$) is then the derivative of $zf(z)$; this immediately gives you the Abel sum as zero

Comment: @Conrad Nicely concise answer, much obliged. I could sense that the pattern was there but it would have probably taken too much of my time to see it.